# How to get the Assets index in looping field tag pair?

Tags: assets

I'm converting some code over from using grid fields with images to use a single Assets field instead.  All good so far.

But I need a way to get at the index (current asset number while looping through the field tag pair).

Looking over the docs, I don't see an obvious way to do this.  {my_asset_field:index} doesn't appear to be a valid expression.

Answer (score 0):

When you say **'index'** do you mean something like the *{count}* variable in a Channel Entries loop?

If so then I believe *(if my memory serves me correctly*) that the files tag pair allows you to use the *{count}* variable inside it.

I really hope I'm not remembering this incorrectly though.

Comment: Yep, you're correct -- see my answer above.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ah excellent. Glad you have it all working now.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct, even though it's not documented anywhere on the Assets documentation, I discovered that {count} does indeed work for it.

If you're like me, and needed an index (zero-based), I found that this plugin will do the trick for you without having to enable PHP for your template page:

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mh-index